# Pyodbc login time out error with (Azure) SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, azure, pyodbc

I am getting a strange error with Python condo environments and PyODBC. I have multiple Conda environments, I am able to connect from one of the environment (from a Linux machine) to SQL Server hosted on Azure but not from the other one. Both Python environments have version 3.7.7 of Python and version 4.0.0 of Pyodbc. Code is exactly the same and connection string uses SQL Server 17 driver.

```
conn_str='DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +server+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+self.user_name+';PWD='+self.password
```

Error is :

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: server is not responding , most probably network issue

Comment: But it is connecting from another Conda environment from the same machine. It means network is fine.

Comment: It can be firewall , port access permission, etc...

Answer (score 0):

- As you can see above, the issue might be DNS-related. In the
  connection string, try using an IP address instead of the hostname,
  or check your DNS setup.
- Try downgrade to ODBC driver 13 and have a try. For that version 17
  needs to be uninstalled.
- Try using connect from SQL Authentication instead of Active Directory
  Password.

The SQL Server ODBC drivers for Linux from Microsoft are unable to determine instance names.